# How to add a filetype mapping to IIS 5 programmatically

Tags: iis, iis-5

I want to add .doc to my mapped file extensions in IIS 5.1 as part of my build script. Is there a script or some example code somewhere that I could include that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a script at http://www.iisfaq.com/Default.aspx?tabid=2792 that seems to work well.